# After intercepting SIGWINCH in a ncurses-based program, key presses are not recognized

Tags: c, signals, ncurses, window-resize

I have a small ncurses-based program which performs basic chemical calculations. Its main function is like this:

```
int main() {   
  initscr();   
  cbreak();   
  nonl();   
  noecho(); 
  /* draws borderlines from position 0 to (COLS - 1) 
     for purely decorative purposes at the top and bottom
     of the screen */
  draw_GUI(); 
  keypress_loop();   
  endwin(); 
};
```

The `keypress_loop()` function  waits for user to press a key and then prints the key's symbol on the screen if the key is letter or digit and makes a beep if the key is neither letter nor digit. If user presses F2 the function returns and the program ends.

```
void  keypress_loop() 
{
   int key;
   while ((key = wgetch(stdscr)) != KEY_F(2))
      process_key(key); 
}
```

So far everything works as intended. But then I add a signal handler for SIGWINCH to make sure that borderlines are redrawn correctly after resizing the terminal emulator's window. Before `initscr()` in the `main()` function I insert:

```
signal(SIGWINCH, handle_resizing);
```

And `handle_resizing`() looks like this:

```
static void
handle_resizing(int signo) {
      endwin();
      initscr();   
      cbreak();   
      nonl();   
      noecho();
      draw_GUI();
}
```

This SIGWINCH-handling function redraws the borderlines as intended. But the problem is that, when user presses a key after resizing, the program ignores this key. And only after user presses a key three or more times the program starts recognizing the key and then everything works OK! How can I make the program to immediately recognize key presses after resizing?

Comment: There is no obvious reason for the behaviour you describe, perhaps a real mcve would help here (i.e. a complete code example reproducing the issue)

Comment: Is it possible that handling SIGWINCH  temporarily blocks something inside ncurses library?

Comment: It is probably unsafe to do it this way and prone of races, so yes, you should better set a global flag on SIGWINCH instead of calling the functions there. But this is probably not the root cause of your issue here

Comment: Your way of handling the signal looks dangerous. Don't do this. Do what ncurses manual [recommends](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html), i.e. read KEY_RESIZE and update from there. endwin/initscr pair will clear the screen and probably look bad. It's not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `handle_resizing` function calls functions which are unsafe to use in a signal handler.  The [`resizeterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h2-NOTES) manual page has a section discussing this.  Your program should use the [`KEY_RESIZE`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) return value from `getch`.

Comment: I followed Thomas Dickey's `KEY_RESIZE`-related advice by removing `signal(SIGWINCH, handle_resizing);` and adding `else if (key == KEY_RESIZE) handle_resizing()` to the `keypress_loop()`. Now everything is OK! Even the resizing process seems to be done smoother!